# UIStackView: consistent height based on all subviews even if they are missing

Tags: swift, autolayout, uilabel, uistackview

I've got a StackView with two labels as the arrangedSubviews. I want the StackView to be always the height of those two labels (including DynamicType changes), even if one of the labels text it nil or empty (which normally changes the stack views height to the height of that single label).

I tried to sketch the problem, in hope that I find a great solution. (I cannot simply put a height constraint to the stack view, because dynamicType changes the height of the labels).

[image]

Comment: You could add a height constraint and activate/deactivate depending on how many labels there's gonna be.

Comment: What should happen if **BOTH** labels are empty/nil?

Comment: And... do both labels use the same font? either or both labels potentially more than one line?

Comment: Oh... and if one label is empty, you want the other label to be centered vertically, while maintaining the height as if both labels are there?

Comment: @DonMag: That won't be the case, because LABEL A either has text or has a default text. Both labels have different font weights and potentially heights. They have only one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to try to use a stack view for this.

Instead, create a custom `UIView`, with **three** labels:

- Top label

  - Top constrained to the view Top
- Bottom label

  - Top constrained to the bottom of the Top label (with desired space)
  - Bottom constrained to the view Bottom
- Center label

  - constrained centerY to the view

Then:

- If both labels have text

  - show them and hide the center label
- If only one label has text

  - give them both " " as text
  - hide them both
  - show the center label
  - set the center label's text and font to the respective top or bottom label

Here's an example:

**Custom View**

```
class WalterView: UIView {

    let labelA = UILabel()
    let labelB = UILabel()
    let labelC = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        for (v, c) in zip([labelA, labelB, labelC], [UIColor.cyan, UIColor.green, UIColor.yellow]) {
            addSubview(v)
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
                v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            ])
            v.backgroundColor = c
            v.textAlignment = .center
        }

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            labelA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            labelB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelA.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            labelB.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            
            labelC.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        labelA.text = " "
        labelB.text = " "
        labelC.isHidden = true
        
        // set fonts as desired
        labelA.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
        labelB.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .subheadline)
        labelA.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        labelB.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        
    }
    
    func setLabels(topLabel strA: String, botLabel strB: String) -> Void {

        if !strA.isEmpty && !strB.isEmpty {
            
            // if neither string is empty
            //  show A & B
            //  set text for A & B
            //  hide C

            labelA.text = strA
            labelB.text = strB
            labelC.text = ""
            labelA.isHidden = false
            labelB.isHidden = false
            labelC.isHidden = true
            
        } else {
            
            // if either top or bottom string is empty
            //  hide A & B
            //  show C
            //  set A & B text to " " (so they're not empty)
            //  set text for C to the non-empty string
            //  set C's font & background color to respective top or bottom label

            labelA.isHidden = true
            labelB.isHidden = true
            labelC.isHidden = false

            labelA.text = " "
            labelB.text = " "

            if strA.isEmpty {
                labelC.text = strB
                labelC.backgroundColor = labelB.backgroundColor
                guard let f = labelB.font else {
                    return
                }
                labelC.font = f
            }
            
            if strB.isEmpty {
                labelC.text = strA
                labelC.backgroundColor = labelA.backgroundColor
                guard let f = labelA.font else {
                    return
                }
                labelC.font = f
            }

        }
        
    }

}
```

**Example Controller** - each tap will cycle through "both", "Top Only" and "Bottom Only":

```
class WalterViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var wView = WalterView()
    
    var idx: Int = 0
    
    var testStrings: [[String]] = [
        ["Top Label",   "Bottom Label"],
        ["Top Only",    ""],
        ["",            "Bottom Only"],
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        wView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(wView)
        
        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            wView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            wView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            wView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            
            // NO Height constraint...
            // height will be determined by wView's labels
        ])
        
        // so we can see the frame of wView
        wView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        wView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        
        updateLabels()
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        updateLabels()
    }
    
    func updateLabels() -> Void {
        let strs = testStrings[idx % testStrings.count]
        wView.setLabels(topLabel: strs[0], botLabel: strs[1])
        idx += 1
    }
    
}
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

[image]